# How to get the reception signal power value in simulation script?

Tags: unetstack

I have a channel model, where some transmission loss is calculated, If I have to test it against different values of frequency and print the values calculated in     **getRxPower(rx)**    function in simulation script, how can I access this value in the simulation script.

Comment: Why not simply print the value in the channel model class?

Comment: Yes, I can do that for my channel model. But I  also want to print the values from UrickAcousticModel ( [ https://www.unetstack.net/javadoc/org/arl/unet/sim/channels/UrickAcousticModel.html] ). @Mandar Chitre

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way may be to create your own channel model that extends the `UrickAcousticModel`, override the `getRxPower()` method, and log the return value of the original method before returning it.

This might look something like:

```
public class MyUrickAcousticModel extends org.arl.unet.sim.channels.UrickAcousticModel {

  protected Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());

  @Override
  public double getRxPower(org.arl.unet.sim.Reception rx) {
    double v = super.getRxPower(rx);
    log.info("getRxPower returned "+v);
    return v;
  }

}
```

You can then use this model in your simulation, exactly in the same way as the `UrickAcousticModel`.